# Comparing 2 columns from 2 dataframe on python

Tags: python, pandas, match, matching, string-matching

I have the following 2 dataframes:

```
Work_Order,Manual_Report

0001,APU AUTO SHOTDOWN ON THE FIRST START  
0002,AIR PACK 2 ON ECAM DURING INITIAL CLIMB  
0003,AUTO FLT FCU 1 FAULT CLIMBING FL 380

Report_database

APU AUTO SHUT DOWN  
AIR PACK 2 FAULT  
AUTO FLT FCU 1 FAULT
```

And I want the following output:

```
Work_Order,Manual_Report,Report  _database

0001,APU AUTO SHOTDOWN ON THE FIRST START,APU AUTO SHUT DOWN    
0002,AIR PACK 2 ON ECAM DURING INITIAL CLIMB,AIR PACK 2 FAULT    
0003,AUTO FLT FCU 1 FAULT CLIMBING FL 380,AUTO FLT FCU 1 FAULT
```

Is there any function or library on python to match string values to the closest one comparing with a database? consider that the first DF is a manual input and typo errors can be founded and additional characters typed.

Comment: Please rephrase and reformat your question and examples. Also, a code sample might be helpful

Comment: You need to come up with a string matching condition, i.e. how many  character mismatches are you willing to accept between two strings considered equal.

Comment: Thank You! It worked with the link above. I only have an additional question: is it possible to make it faster? I have a lot of information to compare.